# Can I force to check emails three times per day?

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

I'd like to continue to use Gmail from my web browser. I'd also like to see new emails at set times during the day, so I don't look at my Gmail many times in one day.

The ideal is to have Gmail refresh with new messages at 8a, 1p and 5p. Is that possible to implement without switching clients to something like superhuman?

Comment: If you keep the webpage open it usually refreshes.

Comment: How can I stop that behavior? I know there's a marketplace of extensions.

Comment: That what I don't understand, why do you want that? Just do not open it unless on those 3 times of the day you mentioned. And no, there's nothing for that purpose applicable to the webpage. Standalone email clients like Outlook or Thunderbird do allow for a schedule.

Comment: Are you positive there is no work-around?

Comment: Your question was moved to the appropriate website. If the answer below serves your purpose you should accept it.

Answer (score -1):

- go to **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox**
- right-click the Gmail tab
- select **Pin tab**

  [image: 0]
- as soon as you receive a new email the counter will rise

  [image: 0]

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for. The OP wants to have the page open but it to refresh only 3 times a day at specific hours (!!!). I wonder why they can't just open it when they want to check email then close it like everybody else...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia true, however, I believe the issue is something like "how to check for new messages without constantly opening and closing the tab" eg. pinning it saves space and indicator shows new messages so no need to enter the tab to check if there is something in the inbox